# TCPDF - Renderizar un conjunto de tablas

Tags: pdf

Saludos. Quisiera saber si es posible renderizar un conjunto de tablas mediante ajax, estoy usando TCPDF con la Version: 6.0.021

Actualmente puedo renderizar y crear tablas en pdf de la manera comun, es decir:

```
<form method="POST" action="rutatcpdf.php">
conjunto de datos de tabla
</form>
```

Comment: Hola osmelg, esta pregunta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad y puede acabar cerrada. Por favor, lee [ask] y edita la pregunta para añadir más detalles (¿qué es lo que estás intentando hacer?¿qué has intentado?¿con qué dificultades te estás encontrando?) y concretarla un poco más.

Comment: hola @AlvaroMontoro ¿qué es lo que estás intentando hacer?Quisiera saber si es posible renderizar un conjunto de tablas ¿con qué dificultades te estás encontrando? renderizar un conjunto de tablas mediante ajax. concretarla un poco más, acabo de actualizar lo que puedo realizar hasta ahora